# Migração do angular material 5 para o angular material 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Estou migrando do angular 5 para o 6 e do material 5 para o 6. O problema é que ocorre o segundo erro ao subir a aplicação.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at MatCommonModule.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js.MatCommonModule._checkThemeIsPresent (core.es5.js:141)
at new MatCommonModule (core.es5.js:93)
at _createClass (core.js:8116)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:8088)
at initNgModule (core.js:8024)
at new NgModuleRef_ (core.js:8747)
at createNgModuleRef (core.js:8736)
at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (core.js:10561)
at NgModuleFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleFactory_.create (core.js:11263)
at core.js:4161
```

Até agora não vi nenhuma solução para resolver o problema.

Answer (score 0):

A solução encontrada para este problema é a seguinte. No arquivo app.module.ts dentro dos providers deve ser colocado o seguinte código:

```
 {
    provide: MATERIAL_SANITY_CHECKS, 
    useValue: false
 }
```

Este comando significa que não será checado se foi utilizado algum tema do angular material, assim o código funcionara com temas externos sem erro.